# IOS Framework into ANE

Tags: adobe-native-extensions

How can I embed a framework into an Adobe Native Extension?

I used the platforms options, but when I try to compile Flash show an id64 error.

On a Mac is possible copy the frameworks into the Xcode folder, but I need embed the frameworks to compile in a PC running Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the extension to zip
- copy all the files into a folder
- add the header of each framework